# Making nav work on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I posted a question last night about using media queries [Fixed header and a responsive website issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753512/fixed-header-and-a-responsive-website-issue)

So I thought I finally cracked it but what seems to happen is when the screen is resized down the text jumps to the left and disappears. I thought all i had to do was make the `#nav-wrapper` the same size and the screen it will be on.

Here is the code

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<nav id="main-nav">
    <div class="inner-nav" id="nav-wrapper">        
            <div class="ten columns">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Test</a></li>
            </div>
    </div>
</nav>


</body>
</html>
```

**CSS** - In Scss format as the CSS is compressed

```
//Navigation
#main-nav {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
box-shadow: 0 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
-webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
-moz-transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
-ms-transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
-o-transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
display: block;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
float: left;
width: 100%;
z-index: 12;
height: 60px;
background-color: white;

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.inner-nav {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 800px;
}

ul {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    width: 600px;

    li {
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: inline;
        margin: 0 2px;
        color: black;
        list-style-type: none;

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

    }

}
}
```

And the media query I am calling

```
/* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #nav-wrapper{
        width:767px;
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me what I have to do so when the screen is mobile lets say the nav just resizes to fit the screen. Also I know the `position:fixed`that how i want it so when the user scrolls the nav bar stays at the top. Although if there is a way to make the nav cover the top of the whole site I then wouldnt have to use`position:fixed` as the framework I am using (http://www.getskeleton.com/) doesn't seem to allow me to do this.

I am trying to have a design like https://simple.com/ although not with the jQuery stuff just the nav at the top then the header across the page and content under. I have tried looks at their source but they are using custom style sheets and they are also compressed.

EDIT

It may not be clear what I am after, I want a website with a fixed header which is also responsive so on mobile devices it will fit the screen. The simple site is something im working off if anyone knows how they did there site im all ears.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see with your media query is that when the screen has a width bellow 767px you're telling the css processor to render the nav-wrapper element with a width of 767px. So, if a user accesses the page via a 480px width device, it would overflow the screen.

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish, but my best suggest is to set the width to 100% in your media query (or delete it completely, and inherit the width:100% from the previous CSS declaration for that element).

Comment: Thats what I think I just worked out. But then what is the correct way to do it when the user is on a 480px device? Setting the width to 100% or removing it doesn't solve the issue as then its acting like there is no media query there.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do, after reading your previous question.I wouldn't use a media query at all, since media queries are use (mainly) to modify the way an element is represented by means of CSS. If you're trying to preserve the default look appearance of the element, then there's no need to modify its original width. Maybe you need to adjust the elements inside the nav, because maybe they just don't fit. If you were able to post a screenshot of the problem, it would be great!

Comment: What I am after is a site like this https://simple.com/ In other words a fixed nav, when the site is viewed on a mobile it shrinks down and the nav changes. That is media queries im guessing? Is there a template any where for sites like this? Header/content across screen/content.

Comment: My issue is I have the header in place but when it shrinks any text jumps to the left and goes off the screen like you said. What i want is when the screen is made smaller for it to shrink down to the correct size for the browser.

Comment: Okay, so I would suggest that every width attribute should be expressed on percentages. Once you do so, you'll see how the elements resize to the current screen width.